How can I save the output of softwareupdate --list as variable in bash on macOS?
I tried:
updates=( $(softwareupdate --list) )

It catches:
echo $updates
Software Update Tool

Finding available software

Instead of the full output:
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
No new software available.

Have no clue how to solve this problem.

Are you sure you're using bash?

That looks like what I'd expect your output to be on zsh. With the exact code you ran I'd expect on bash the output to be only the word Software. (zsh is default on MacOS, since Apple is unwilling to agree to GPLv3 license terms to be able to distribute modern releases of bash, so it seems likely you're actually using zsh and tagged the question with the wrong shell).

That some parts of the output are not captured probably means that those parts are written to the command's standard error stream instead of its standard output stream.  This is a feature, not a bug, but if you want to catch both ordinary and diagnostic output together then you can simply redirect the command's standard error stream to be the same as its standard output stream:
softwareupdate --list 2>&1

The 2>&1 says to make file descriptor 2 (standard error) refer to the same open file description as file descriptor 1 (standard output).  It can appear at any point on the command line, including before the command, but it is conventional to put redirections at the end.

As a separate matter, using the output directly to initialize an array, as in your example, is probably going to cause you trouble.  As written, you will get each whitespace-delimited word as a separate array element, but I anticipate that what you really want is one array element for each whole line of input.  The mapfile builtin serves that purpose.  For instance, you might do this:
updates=()
mapfile -t updates < <(softwareupdate --list 2>&1)

The first < is the usual input redirection operator.  The <(some command) is a bashism that designates the name of a file from which the standard output of some command can be read.  This somewhat unusual thing works around an issue that your particular script would have with the usual mechanism (piping) for feeding the output of one command into the input of a different one.

I cannot check as I do not have macOS, but I think the line missing from your input might go to stderr, but operator $( ... ) only capture stdout
I could try to redirect stderr to stdout:
updates=( $(softwareupdate --list 2>& 1) )

Also, I am surprise by the example you give: you set updates as an array, but displayed it as a string. It should only display the first word

you set updates as an array, but displayed it as a string. It should only display the first word I bet OP is actually using zsh, not bash, since that's the default shell on Macs and that's how it expands arrays when just the name is given.
